# GIT: revert selected commits since a certain commit, release, then reapply them

Tags: git, release-management

There are a load of commits for two bugfixes ***X*** and ***Y*** pushed to a release branch in a remote repository. The last stable release from the branch was done after commit ***a***.

[image]
Bugfix ***X*** is done but bugfix ***Y*** is still ongoing. The ***x*** commits are mixed up with the ***y*** commits.

The original intention was to release bugfixes ***X*** and ***Y*** together, but things have changed and it's decided we need to release the fix for ***X*** *right now*.

Speaking conceptually this means I have to remove all the ***y*** commits and keep all the ***x*** commits since commit ***a*** - then release bugfix ***X*** from the branch - and then reapply all the ***y*** commits again so work can resume on bugfix ***Y***.

One solution I thought about is to just branch from commit ***a*** and cherry pick **x1**, **x2** and **x3** to the new branch, then just release from there. However, unfortunately this isn't possible as I *have to* release from this branch and continue working on it afterwards (don't ask me why, I just do :))

This isn't a problem I've encountered before with GIT so I'm unsure what potential patterns there are for solving it. So, **what is the most elegant way to achieve my goal?**

I want a solution that uses minimal steps, preserves the true history of the branch before it was applied (*i.e. I strictly cannot rebase!*), and does not requiring manual file editing, with the possible exception of merges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>*The most elegant way is to rebase --interactive*</strike>

**Update** Since you clarified that *this* isn't even an option, clearly you have `revert` and `cherry-pick` left (like an accountant: no deletions, but 'counter-bookings').

This can get tedious. However, you can use UI's to your advantage. Or you can automate things:

> **UPDATE** I've made a complete self-contained demo **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c55fde887ebfaa8)**

If you can 'grep' the commits for issue-tracker IDs, you could automate things. Here's a demo assuming you used ticket number `#724` in the commit messages. (Note how it limits the range of commits to grep by doing `a..HEAD` (replace `a` by the relevant commit-id or tag):

```
$ culprits=$(git rev-list --grep='#724' a..HEAD)
$ do git revert --no-edit $culprits
```

now do your release!

```
$ git tag RELEASE_20130913   # or, maybe, do the release immediately
    $ git cherry-pick $culprits
```

if you mess up, just `git reset --hard 'commit'` (with 'commit' referring to the last commit before the first `revert`).

---

Original answer:

The most elegant way is to rebase --interactive

```
git rebase -i a
```

Many git gui tools make it exceptionally easy to do this (TortoiseGit on windows, very nice). However, I have no trouble following the instructions on screen in the command-line version (which let's you 'edit rebase-plan' in a text editor).

So your rebase will come up with e.g.

```
pick a comment1
pick x1 comment2
pick y1 comment3
pick x2 comment4
pick x3 comment5
pick y2 comment6
```

Just reorder:

```
pick a comment1
pick x1 comment2
pick x2 comment4
pick x3 comment5
pick y1 comment3
pick y2 comment6
```

> **Note** This *does* rewrite history since after the `x1` commit (but that's not released yet, and you can probably decide whether it's a problem with your co-workers who might have to rebase their changes onto the newer HEAD now). Just fair warning.

And done!

---

After the rebase, just tag the new revision `x3` (with "comment5"), e.g.

```
git tag release_20130912 HEAD~2
```

and release *that*. It will still be from the current branch, which already has the two `y1`,`y2` commits as well.

Comment: Helpful answer, but I *really* can't use rebase because of the rewriting history on the 'central' repository problem. I'll make this more prominent in the question.

Comment: What do you expect to do, then? You can simply `git revert y1; git revert y2`, release, `git cherry-pick y1 y2` and be done

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about `cherry-pick`ing old commits from the same branch, this would solve the re-application of the y commits nicely. I has been thinking about `revert`ing each individual unwanted commit to get the branch to the releasable state - it's a little manual if there are many more commits than this simple example (which, actually, there are ;), but if there's no simpler way...

Comment: @davnicwil If you have something in the commit messages/patches that you can grep for, you can automate this. It's just three lines in a shell (see my updated answer)

Comment: Here's a **[complete selfcontained _live_ demo script](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c55fde887ebfaa8)** (yay for Coliru) so you can see what I mean!